# Simplest implementation of "lightweight type categorization idiom"?

Tags: c++, c++11

My goal is to implement a predicate that detects the presence of a nested `using` alias (or `typedef`) that acts as a light-weight tag to indicate that a class has some attribute (for the purposes of generic programming). For example, a `has_my_tag<T>` predicate should behave as follows:

```
struct A {
  using my_tag = void;
};

struct B {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(has_my_tag<A>::value, "");  // evaluate to true if my_tag=void is present
    static_assert(!has_my_tag<B>::value, ""); // false otherwise
}
```

User @JoelFalcou called this the "lightweight type categorization idiom" and provided a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644512/2013747). I have been unable to find any references for an idiom of that name (do you know of any?) Here's Joel's implementation of `has_my_tag<>`:

```
template<class T, class R = void>  
struct enable_if_type { typedef R type; };

template<class T, class Enable = void>
struct has_my_tag : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_my_tag<T, typename enable_if_type<typename T::my_tag>::type> : 
std::true_type
{};
```

And here is a working version on the Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/EEOBb-

I have come up with the following simplified version:

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>
struct has_my_tag : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_my_tag<T, typename T::my_tag> : std::true_type
{};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/yhkHp7

**My Questions:** Is the simplified version an acceptable way to implement the idiom? Are there circumstances where it would fail? Is there a simpler version that works in C++11? Which version should I prefer?

From what I understand, Joel's version would allow `my_tag` to alias any type, whereas my version requires `my_tag` to alias `void`. But given the goal of tagging types for light-weight predicate testing, I am not clear which version is to be preferred.

Auxiliary questions: Also, are there other names for this idiom? Is it used in any libraries that I could investigate? So far I have not found a name that brings up any search results.

Comment: Whether "the simplified version an acceptable way to implement the idiom" obviously depends entirely on whether it works correctly. That's your decision to make, alone. Does it work correctly, for your intended purposes, or not. This is something you can simply write test cases for, and if the end result is correct, then it is "an acceptable way to implement this idiom". You should not expect anyone to tell you "which version should [you] prefer". You can make that decision yourself. And, lastly, as far as whether there are "other names" for this: unfortunately I don't play buzzword bingo.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the purpose of using idioms is to be consistent and familiar with the reader's expectations. Your advice seems to suggest that code which is obscure, unfamiliar, and unidiomatic is perfectly acceptable so long as it passes tests. I disagree.

Comment: Why exactly is using the simplest implementation of relevance? Put the implementation details in an inner namespace and no user of `has_my_tag` will ever have to care about it...

Comment: Your version would require a name change, as you require also that `my_tag` is `void`.

Comment: I would call it detect idiom (even if there are several different implementation (as [std::experimental::is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your setup, there is no difference between the original version and yours. Both use SFINAE to select the correct has_my_tag. Your version does however constrain your `typedef/using` to be `my_tag=void`. if my_tag is typedef'd as any other type, your specialization will not match, and you will end up instantiating the primary template as can be seen [here](https://ideone.com/l2KfNF).

The reason for this is that where you instanciate the templates in main, `static_assert(has_my_tag<A>::value, "");` you are not specifying the second parameter, so the default (void) is used, that is `has_my_tag<A,void>::value`

Your specialization must match this to be considered.

The usage of `enable_if_type`, (basically doing the job of [void_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) in c++17) is to enable SFINAE on the `::type` member of T, but then always result in void, such that your specialization will match when `::type` exists, regardless of the type of the `my_tag` typedef.

This allows you to just worry about whether it exists, and not its type;

Personally I would use the approach that doesn't depend on `my_type` being typedef'd as void, either the enable_if_type version, or something like...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  using my_tag = void;
};

struct B {};

struct C {
  using my_tag = int; // with void_t also works with my_tag = int
};

struct D {
  struct my_tag{}; //or some struct as the tag
};

// same as your enable_if_type
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;


template<class T, class Enable = void>
struct has_my_tag : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_my_tag<T, void_t<typename T::my_tag>> : std::true_type
{};


int main() {
    std::cout << has_my_tag<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_my_tag<B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_my_tag<C>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_my_tag<D>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9zfOHC)

Comment: I have to say that the way the specialization interacts here (and in the OP) can be unintuitive. If I understand correctly, an instantiation of the template will deduce `has_my_tag<T, void>` by the `false_type` version's template signature, then substitute `T` into both versions and finally match the `true_type` version due to it being more specialized. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you got it right. It is simply that when instantiating has_my_tag<T> it uses the default value, yeilding has_my_tag<T,void>. The default is only relevant when instanciating. When templates and specializations are considered, the default value can be ignored, and you are left with <class T, class Enable>  (primary template) and a specialization <class T,void>. The <T,void> is obviously more specialized for these types and thus chosen - like this https://ideone.com/LA6Plr - It's a shame that something actually so simple is made look so unintuitive and complicated with c++.

Comment: Ok, good! I agree that the main confusion stems from the `false_type` template signature being "touched" even when you get the `true_type` one in the end. This of course always happens with every "base case + specializations" templates, but it's not something you'd usually have to consider to understand which version is picked.

Answer (score 3):

First, yours works, but does depend on it being `void`.  That lightweight tag might be useful if it carried a non-void type in some situations, and if it is non-void you silently get detection failing, which seems bad.

Second, your type tagging *require* you to modify the type, which means you cannot get built-in or types you don't own (like ones in `std`).  We can fix this.

```
namespace type_tag {

  namespace adl {
    template<template<class...>class tag>
    struct tag_token_t {};

    template<class T, template<class...> class tag>
    constexpr
    decltype( (void)(std::declval<tag<T>>()), std::true_type{} )
    tag_test( T*, tag_token_t<tag> ) { return {}; }

    template<class T, template<class...> class tag, class...LowPriority>
    constexpr
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T,int>{}, std::false_type> tag_test(T*, tag_token_t<tag>, LowPriority&&...) {
      return {};
    }
  }
  template<template<class...>class Z>using tag_token_t = adl::tag_token_t<Z>;

  template<template<class...>class tag>
  constexpr tag_token_t<tag> tag_token{};

  namespace details {
    template<class T, template<class...>class tag>
    constexpr auto test_impl( T*, tag_token_t<tag> ) {
      return tag_test( (T*)nullptr, tag_token<tag> );
    }
  }
  template<class T, template<class>class tag>
  constexpr auto tag_test() {
    return details::test_impl((T*)nullptr, tag_token<tag>);
  }
}
```

so now a tag is this:

```
template<class T>
using my_tag = typename T::my_tag;
```

we can test it as follows:

```
constexpr auto double_has_tag = type_tag::tag_test< double, my_tag >();
```

which returns a compile-time true or false if `double` has a tag.

We can decide that `int` has a tag by doing:

```
namespace type_tag::adl {
  constexpr std::true_type tag_test( int*, type_tag::tag_token_t<my_tag> ) {
    return {};
  }
}
```

or, for types that we control:

```
struct my_tagged_type {
  using my_tag = void;
};
```

for types we can inject names into their namespace (ie, not `std` or built-in types) we can do:

```
namespace not_my_ns {
  constexpr std::true_type tag_test( not_my_type*, ::tag_test::tag_token_t<::my_tag> ) {
    return {};
  }
}
```

and suddenly `type_tag::tag_test<not_my_ns::not_my_type, ::my_tag>()` is truthy.

Once we have `tag_test< type, tag_name >()` we can use the usual `std::enable_if` instead of some custom system.

The advantages of this system include:

1. It can be extended without changing anything about the type you are tagging.
2. It can be extended using the `using tag=void;` or `using tag=int;` that your system works with.
3. At SFINAE point of use, it is just another compile-time `bool`.  So your existing SFINAE patterns work with it.
4. If you pick a poor name for the tag type in the struct that someone else is using for an unrelated reason, `tag_test` can override this on a per-type basis.

The disadvantage is that it took a bit of magic to do this.  But in common use cases, you get the same work required for end-users as your lightweight system.  In more complex use cases, this lets you do things your lightweight one won't.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b2ca5925662cd7e).