# Is there any way to check if a template class has a nested class definition (or a typedef) in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I have the following structures defined:

```
struct NoRelationship {};
struct OneToMany      {};
struct Interdependent {};

template <typename RelationType>
struct SignatureGenerator
{
    using type = std::function<void()>;
};

template <>
struct SignatureGenerator<Interdependent>
{
    using type = std::function<void()>;
    using extra_type = std::function<void()>;
};
```

I need to implement a SFINAE check which would determine if a class has the "extra_type" definition. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644477/how-to-check-whether-a-class-has-specified-nested-class-definition-or-typedef-in) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function) topics, but still can't find a working solution. I have tried the following code from the latter topic:

```
template <typename T>
class has_extra_type
{
    typedef char yes;
    struct no {char x[2];};
    template<typename C> static yes test(decltype(&C::extra_type));
    template<typename C> static no test(...);
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof (char)};
};
```

But this doesn't work, because of the 'missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name' error. That is what the compiler tells if I comment out the general specification:

```
//    template<typename C> static no test(...);
```

error: no matching function for call to 'test'
enum { value = sizeof(test(0)) == sizeof (char)};

note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with C = SignatureGenerator]: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'SignatureGenerator::extra_type'
template static yes test(decltype(&C::extra_type));

Any ideas on how to bypass this?

*Update: here is how I use the checks:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << has_extra_type<SignatureGenerator<OneToMany>>::value <<std::endl;
    std::cout << has_extra_type<SignatureGenerator<Interdependent>>::value <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives 0 for both of the classes, while I expected the 'extra_type' to be detected in the second case.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Can you show how you're using `has_extra_type`? Maybe the issue lies there.

Comment: No, I don' think there is an issue there, please, see the updated question.

Comment: You might be interested by: [`std::experimental::is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `yes` overload, you are using:

```
template<typename C> static yes test(decltype(&C::extra_type)); // incorrect for types
```

However, the `decltype` and `&` is only needed because the example that you were looking at was checking for the existence of a *member function*. But `extra_type` is a type, and so you can't take its address, and so that expression is always ill-formed, and the overload is never chosen.

Since you're checking for the existence of a *member type alias*, you can simply do:

```
template<typename C> static yes test(typename C::extra_type*);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fszns9).

Comment: @cigien, yes, you're right, works fine, thanks a lot! 'typename', though, is indeed required.

Comment: @AntonPilyak I missed the C++14 in the question, my bad. I've edited the answer.